# Braintree - Error Setting Up Advanced Fraud Tools On Android

Tags: android, braintree

We're already setup with `Braintree`, I'm having issues setting up our Android project with Braintree's Advanced Fraud Tools. We’ve followed all of the instructions [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/advanced-fraud-tools/client-side/android/v2)

I'm getting the following error message when we run the app after the library is imported through `Gradle`.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':App:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/devicecollector/AbstractCollectorProcess.class
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant portion of your `build.gradle`? Some how you're including http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.braintreepayments.api%7Cdata-collector%7C2.2.1%7Cjar twice